# How to create an Access DB with vba / c# (DBMS)

Tags: c#, ms-access, vba

I have seen some tutorials but everything that I am trying is not working.

I want a simple project with just one textbox (where the name of the database goes) and a button that creates the`Access` DB and save it in `c:\`.

May you help me ? :)

Comment: how about the fields ? ..

Comment: What fields? The application has just 1 textbox and 1 button. I put the name of the db into the textbox and when I click in the button it create a db with the name typed in the textbox and save it in "c:\".
The database is just empty.

Comment: sorry .. I mean with no table ?

Comment: Yes, because i'm just having trouble creating the Access db. All the table and 'content' part I already know how to do it using oledb. I just don't know how to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new, empty Access database, all you need to do is to add a COM reference to

"Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security"

to your project, and then use code like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace adoxTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=C:\__tmp\myDB.accdb;";

            // the following code requires a COM reference to "Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security"
            var cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
            cat.Create(myConnectionString);  // create a new, empty .accdb file

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to go "old school" and create an `.mdb` file using Jet, then just use the following connection string instead...

```
string myConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=C:\__tmp\myDB.mdb;";
```

...but be warned that this will fail if your application is running as 64-bit (because there is no 64-bit version of the Jet database engine).

Comment: Oh man, thank you! All the answers were right, but in my opinion your was the most specefic one. 
My problem was just the "COM reference" part, all the codes I tried were correct, man you make someone very happy today! :D

Answer (score 1):

**You will need catlogclass for this as follows:**

```
CatalogClass catcls = new CatalogClass();  
string tmpStr;  
string filename = txtFileName.Text+".MDB";   
tmpStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";   
tmpStr += "Data Source=" + filename + ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5";  
catcls.Create(tmpStr);
```

**Next Step Is To Creat Table:**

```
Table nTable = new Table(); 
 nTable.Name = "tlbData"; 
 nTable.Columns.Append("FName", DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 25);
 catcls.Tables.Append(nTable);
```

**Release The COM objects with following code:**

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(nTable); 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(catcls.Tables);    
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(catcls.ActiveConnection); 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(catcls);
```

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: Why when I try to put this cod into an event (button_click) it shows:
"The type or namespace name 'CatalogClass' could not be found" ?

Comment: Import necessary files for it

Comment: MAN PLEASE! I tryed everything, may you please teach me step by step how to do it?

Comment: no buddy, i dont have that much time. Please go through any tutorial, Best Of Luck

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically .. Create MDB in VB Net, use this function

```
Public Function CreateAccessDatabase( _
    ByVal DatabaseFullPath As String) As Boolean
        Dim bAns As Boolean
        Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog()
        Try


         'Make sure the folder
         'provided in the path exists. If file name w/o path 
         'is  specified,  the database will be created in your
         'application folder.

            Dim sCreateString As String
            sCreateString = _
              "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
               DatabaseFullPath
            cat.Create(sCreateString)

            bAns = True

        Catch Excep As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
            bAns = False
            'do whatever else you need to do here, log, 
            'msgbox etc.
        Finally
            cat = Nothing
        End Try
        Return bAns
    End Function
'DEMO
'      If CreateAccessDatabase("F:\test.mdb") = True Then
'           MsgBox("Database Created")
'      Else
'           MsgBox("Database Creation Failed")
'      End If
```

### [source](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5797)

Or In easy way ..

1. Create your MDB or ACCDB with your MS-Access .. you can named it as Template.MDB
2. When user input something in your textbox, you can do this

`My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(d & "Template.MDB", textbox1.text & _   ".MDB",FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)`

dont forger about target path ..